# MySQL Version '5.7.14' SET pProd := pFac1 * pFac2;

Tags: mysql

The following 'CREATE PROCEDURE' statement from [MySQL Connector/Python Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html) is not working in MySQL Version '5.7.14':

```
CREATE PROCEDURE multiply(IN pFac1 INT, IN pFac2 INT, OUT pProd INT)
BEGIN
  SET pProd := pFac1 * pFac2;
END;
```

Please help fix this error:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: delimiter wrapper maybe?

Comment: also maybe just make a function out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a delimiter wrapper

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS multiply;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE multiply(IN pFac1 INT, IN pFac2 INT, OUT pProd INT)
BEGIN
  SET pProd := pFac1 * pFac2;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```